# what is the best way to host angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, tomcat

I have developed application using angularjs as front-end , spring mvc as back-end and i used node js in between them.

I hosted frontend on appache web server and backend on tomcat?

Is this right way?

I am getting CORs issues in IE browser and page response time is very slow.

Can i run both applications on tomcat?How?

Thanks In advance
Raja

Comment: How did you develop that application without knowledge of a web server?

Comment: Actually am a php developer, don't have sound knowledge on tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host both on the same tomcat server (this is exactly what i'm doing).
The web pages (angularJS app) just need to be a part of your server side artifact.
if you're using spring mvc that means your angular files need to be inside your WebContent folder.
then you can set up your web.xml to direct your visitors to the angular app via a controller call or a link to your index file
for example:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/angularapp/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

hope it helps..